# attributes lost with Gradle manifest merger

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I have an app with several build flavors. Part of my main AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="some.test.app"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="36"
    android:versionName="v1.0.3" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!-- possible values: dev, demo, prod -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="app_build_type"
            android:value="dev" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

A sample flavor-specific (`demo`) manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="some.test.app">

    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="app_build_type"
            android:value="demo"
            tools:replace="value"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the result of gradle merge looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="some.test.app"
    android:versionCode="36" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="some.test.app.MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="app_build_type"
            android:value="demo" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see, most of the nodes and attributes are merged correctly, apart from `manifest.installLocation` and `manifest.versionName`, which disappear completely, while `manifest.versionCode` remains. What is the cause of this and how can I fix the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem by having a UI app and a Service. When the build process did the merge automatically it maintained version 1.0, no matter if both AndroidManifest.xml had the proper version. The solution for me was to add the following two fields in the appropriate build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 664
    versionName "664"
}
```

Where 664 is your version. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu `"Build">>"Edit Flavors"` tab `"Flavors"` and insert Version Code and Version Name there